# How to cancel a Task on Backbutton or OnDisappearing in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms page in which when I go from list tab to detail page the there is multiple API Call Task execute When navigate to detail page I quickly back to list page then the task working continue in background so when again open that list item then the pervious calling not cancel and if I open an other item then the data binding response wrong binding. I want to cancel rest API calling when go to back button cancel background task .How I can Achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CancellationToken and catch an exception of type `TaskCanceledException`, Example in

- [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)
- [Task-cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)